# how to get facebook first_name,second_name in android?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to get facebook credentials to my application. i want to print user first name, second name.

I used this code.

```
fbLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            try {
                fb.logout(getApplicationContext());

                updateButtonImage();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{

            fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new String[]{"email","first_name","second_name"}, new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fbError", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    updateButtonImage();
                    //session.createLoginSession("RandB", emailtext);
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestTab.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }}
});
```

can anyone tell me how to print this first_name, and second_name in new String?`(new String[]{"email","first_name","second_name"})`

**Edited**
Can i get data from this `Bundle values` of oncomplete method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(fb.request("me"));
                String firstName = json.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = json.getString("last_name");

                full_name = firstName + " " + lastName;
                Log.d("Name", firstName + " "+ lastName);

            } catch (Exception error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

By adding this code to onComplete method, we can print first name and the last name of the user.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph) you can see how to fetch the user's data and how to print it, if you want to print the `middle_name` just execute the `user.GetProperty("middle_name")` function.

Comment: i want to get data, by using my code. i want to know, can i do that?. because this method really fix with my application.i just want to print user name.other all functionalities completed this code.